# Maven, Vert.x and JodaTime library - NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, maven, jodatime, vert.x

I have a maven project that uses Vert.x library - http://vertx.io/ (but I doubt this has any meaning).
When I try run my app by using vert.x command:
`vertx runzip target/service-1.0.0-mod.zip -conf config.json`
I'm getting following stacktrace:

```
Exception in Java verticle 
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at com.mycompany.myproject.vertx.Verticle.createConfig(Verticle.java:116)
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.withZoneUTC()Lorg/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter;
at com.mycompany.myproject.mypackage.dao.MyDAO.<clinit>(MyDAO.java:30)
...
```

`JodaTime` part of `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I tried running:
`mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=joda-time`
to see if an old version of JodaTime library is loaded as a dependency but all looks OK:

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.7:tree (default-cli) @ matching-service ---
[INFO] com.mycompany.myproject:service:jar:1.0.0
[INFO] \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.3:compile
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you compiled your `MyDAO` against a different version of JodaTime than you use when running it.
I.e. there must be two different joda-time jars in your workspace and a static block in MyDAO calling `withZoneUTC` - unless you only posted half the stack trace and the problem is in a compiled class from the vertx project. In that case you need to get the joda version that vertx was compiled for.